# Creating Rolling Periods

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sum, aggregate-functions

I am wanting to create a rolling period every 6 months and I am unsure of the best way to do this. I am guessing this might have to been done recursively?

I have a payments table that contains data similar to the following:

```
CREATE TABLE payments
    ([id] int, [payment_month] int, [payment_date] datetime, [payment_amount] int)
;
    
INSERT INTO payments
    ([id], [payment_month], [payment_date], [payment_amount])
VALUES
    (1, 201911, '2019-11-01 00:00:00', 50),
    (1, 201912, '2019-12-01 00:00:00', 50),
    (1, 202001, '2020-01-01 00:00:00', 50),
    (1, 202002, '2020-02-01 00:00:00', 50),
    (1, 202003, '2020-03-01 00:00:00', 50),
    (1, 202004, '2020-04-01 00:00:00', 50),
    (1, 202005, '2020-05-01 00:00:00', 50),
    (1, 202006, '2020-06-01 00:00:00', 25),
    (1, 202007, '2020-07-01 00:00:00', 50),
    (1, 202008, '2020-08-01 00:00:00', 50),
    (1, 202009, '2020-09-01 00:00:00', 15),
    (2, 201911, '2019-11-01 00:00:00', 50),
    (2, 201912, '2019-12-01 00:00:00', 50),
    (2, 202001, '2020-01-01 00:00:00', 25),
    (2, 202002, '2020-02-01 00:00:00', 50),
    (2, 202003, '2020-03-01 00:00:00', 45),
    (2, 202004, '2020-04-01 00:00:00', 45),
    (2, 202004, '2020-04-10 00:00:00', 20),
    (2, 202005, '2020-05-01 00:00:00', 25),
    (3, 202004, '2020-04-01 00:00:00', 50),
    (3, 202005, '2020-05-01 00:00:00', 50),
    (3, 202006, '2020-06-01 00:00:00', 50),
    (3, 202007, '2020-07-01 00:00:00', 50),
    (3, 202008, '2020-08-01 00:00:00', 50),
    (3, 202009, '2020-09-01 00:00:00', 300)
;
```

I also have a calendar table which I am using that returns data like this:

```
CREATE TABLE calendar
    ([CalendarPeriod] int, [CalendarDate] datetime)
;
    
INSERT INTO calendar
    ([CalendarPeriod], [CalendarDate])
VALUES
    (202004, '2020-04-30 00:00:00'),
    (202005, '2020-05-31 00:00:00'),
    (202006, '2020-06-30 00:00:00'),
    (202007, '2020-07-31 00:00:00'),
    (202008, '2020-08-31 00:00:00'),
    (202009, '2020-09-30 00:00:00')
;
```

I am hoping to get an output where each `CalendarPeriod` from `calendar` is paired with itself and the 5 preceding months. `CalendarPeriod` acts as a reporting period and the rolling period for each month is 6 months. My end goal is to join `payment_amounts` via `payment_month` to each reporting period where `payment_month` equals one of the rolling months in a reporting period.

**Edit:**
My expected output for just months and rolling periods would look like the table below. I can manipulate the table to aggregate by `CalendarPeriod` if needed.

```
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| CalendarPeriod | rolling_period | rolling_amount |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| 202004         | 201911         | 100            |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| 202004         | 201912         | 100            |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| 202004         | 202001         | 75             |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| 202004         | 202002         | 100            |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| 202004         | 202003         | 95             |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| 202004         | 202004         | 165            |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| 202005         | 201912         | 100            |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| 202005         | 202001         | 75             |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| 202005         | 202002         | 100            |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| 202005         | 202003         | 95             |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| 202005         | 202004         | 165            |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| 202005         | 202005         | 125            |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| 202006         | 202001         | 75             |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| 202006         | 202002         | 100            |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| 202006         | 202003         | 95             |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| 202006         | 202004         | 165            |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| 202006         | 202005         | 125            |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| 202006         | 202006         | 75             |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| 202007         | 202002         | 100            |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| 202007         | 202003         | 95             |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| 202007         | 202004         | 165            |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| 202007         | 202005         | 125            |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| 202007         | 202006         | 75             |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| 202007         | 202007         | 100            |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| 202008         | 202003         | 95             |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| 202008         | 202004         | 165            |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| 202008         | 202005         | 125            |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| 202008         | 202006         | 75             |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| 202008         | 202007         | 100            |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| 202008         | 202008         | 100            |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| 202009         | 202004         | 165            |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| 202009         | 202005         | 125            |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| 202009         | 202006         | 75             |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| 202009         | 202007         | 100            |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| 202009         | 202008         | 100            |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| 202009         | 202009         | 315            |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
```

```
-- Alternate:
+----------------+----------------+
| CalendarPeriod | rolling_amount |
+----------------+----------------+
| 202004         | 635            |
+----------------+----------------+
| 202005         | 660            |
+----------------+----------------+
| 202006         | 635            |
+----------------+----------------+
| 202007         | 660            |
+----------------+----------------+
| 202008         | 660            |
+----------------+----------------+
| 202009         | 880            |
+----------------+----------------+
```

Thanks in advance for you help.

Comment: Have you tried using a `join` between `calendar` and `calendar` to match the 6 month window?

Comment: I didn't try that yet although I am sure there would be a way to do it. If I can avoid that many joins the better this is part of a larger stored proc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand your question, you want a rolling sum of payments for the last 6 months for each period.

I don't think that you really need the intermediate dataset that you are showing to achieve this goal. You can just use window functions:

```
select c.calendarperiod,
    sum(p.payment_amount) month_amount,
    sum(sum(p.payment_amount)) over(
        order by c.calendarperiod
        rows between 5 preceding and current row
    ) rolling_6_month_amount
from calendar c
left join payments p 
    on  p.payment_date >= datefromparts(year(c.calendardate), month(c.calendardate), 1)
    and p.payment_date <  dateadd(day, 1, c.calendardate)
group by c.calendarperiod
```

The query starts from the calendar, and bring the corresponding payments for each month - I adjusted the date interval, in case there are payments within the very last day of the month. Then, we aggregate by period. Finally, we can use window functions to look back over the last 5 periods and sum the corresponding payments.

Comment: This is close but I don't think the totals match quite as expected. e.g., 202004 should be 635. I want to consider a payment in any rolling period it was made for the `CalendarPeriod`. 202004 should contain payment data between (inclusive) 201911 and 202004 -- @GMB updated

Comment: @tlk27: please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64794361/edit) to show the results you want for your sample data.

Comment: @tlk27: thanks for the edit. The problem is with the calendar table, that starts on Apri 2020, while the data starts on November 2019. If you extend the calendar table, then you get the results you want. See this db fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=eafd0ca09c758f34904d9dc2ef74805e

Comment: thanks for your time and assistance it is greatly appreciated. I was not aware of that `rows between x preceding and current` functionality