# Rolling 6 Month Periods

Tags: sql-server

I have a part of a stored procedure which returns data similar to data below.

```
-- Note: I use this parameter to determine the the last of the 6 reporting periods to display
DECLARE @endMonth CHAR(6) = '202009'

CREATE TABLE Table1
(
    [company] varchar(9), 
    [starting_period] int, 
    [reporting_period] int, 
    [gross] numeric
);
    
INSERT INTO Table1
    ([company], [starting_period], [reporting_period], [gross])
VALUES
    ('company_1', 201911, 202003, 2354.36),
    ('company_1', 201912, 202003, 290),
    ('company_1', 202001, 202003, 4299.98),
    ('company_1', 202002, 202003, 2997.96),
    ('company_1', 201911, 202004, 1644.36),
    ('company_1', 201912, 202004, 240),
    ('company_1', 202001, 202004, 7332.43),
    ('company_1', 202002, 202004, 1429.57),
    ('company_1', 202004, 202004, 1511.25),
    ('company_1', 201911, 202005, 1519.36),
    ('company_1', 201912, 202005, 700),
    ('company_1', 202001, 202005, 1478.87),
    ('company_1', 202002, 202005, 2314),
    ('company_1', 202004, 202005, 5687),
    ('company_1', 201911, 202006, 1519.36),
    ('company_1', 201912, 202006, 100),
    ('company_1', 202001, 202006, 871.4),
    ('company_1', 202002, 202006, 317.51),
    ('company_1', 202004, 202006, 2359.47),
    ('company_1', 201911, 202007, 1519.36),
    ('company_1', 201912, 202007, 150),
    ('company_1', 202001, 202007, 871.4),
    ('company_1', 202002, 202007, 429.34),
    ('company_1', 202004, 202007, 1725.73),
    ('company_1', 201911, 202008, 1519.36),
    ('company_1', 201912, 202008, 150),
    ('company_1', 202001, 202008, 654.97),
    ('company_1', 202002, 202008, 453.34),
    ('company_1', 202004, 202008, 3540.29),
    ('company_1', 201911, 202009, 1444.36),
    ('company_1', 201912, 202009, 150),
    ('company_1', 202001, 202009, 254.97),
    ('company_1', 202002, 202009, 403.34),
    ('company_1', 202004, 202009, 2192.37),
    ('company_2', 201911, 202003, 13530.76),
    ('company_2', 201912, 202003, 555.25),
    ('company_2', 202001, 202003, 12700.03),
    ('company_2', 202002, 202003, 62050),
    ('company_2', 201911, 202004, -10522.76),
    ('company_2', 201912, 202004, 230.25),
    ('company_2', 202001, 202004, 8374.63),
    ('company_2', 202002, 202004, 7412.75),
    ('company_2', 202004, 202004, 17034.51),
    ('company_2', 201911, 202005, 1173),
    ('company_2', 201912, 202005, 230.25),
    ('company_2', 202001, 202005, 1608.55),
    ('company_2', 202002, 202005, 7620.55),
    ('company_2', 202004, 202005, 17640.31),
    ('company_2', 202005, 202005, 1242.93),
    ('company_2', 201911, 202006, 1173),
    ('company_2', 201912, 202006, 280.25),
    ('company_2', 202001, 202006, 478.55),
    ('company_2', 202002, 202006, 371.66),
    ('company_2', 202004, 202006, 7972.67),
    ('company_2', 202005, 202006, 651.93),
    ('company_2', 202006, 202006, 44693.61),
    ('company_2', 201911, 202007, 1534),
    ('company_2', 201912, 202007, 380.88),
    ('company_2', 202001, 202007, 305.46),
    ('company_2', 202002, 202007, 421.66),
    ('company_2', 202004, 202007, 4053.74),
    ('company_2', 202005, 202007, 1552.93),
    ('company_2', 202006, 202007, 20787.43),
    ('company_2', 202007, 202007, 200),
    ('company_2', 201911, 202008, 1173),
    ('company_2', 201912, 202008, 280.25),
    ('company_2', 202001, 202008, 567.62),
    ('company_2', 202002, 202008, 371.66),
    ('company_2', 202004, 202008, 1235),
    ('company_2', 202005, 202008, 8168.53),
    ('company_2', 202006, 202008, 22617.11),
    ('company_2', 202007, 202008, 305),
    ('company_2', 201911, 202009, 1173),
    ('company_2', 201912, 202009, 280.25),
    ('company_2', 202001, 202009, 817.62),
    ('company_2', 202002, 202009, 421.66),
    ('company_2', 202004, 202009, 7473.81),
    ('company_2', 202005, 202009, 901.93),
    ('company_2', 202006, 202009, 7863.36),
    ('company_2', 202007, 202009, 280),
    ('company_2', 202008, 202009, 219.66),
    ('company_3', 202005, 202005, 2497.62),
    ('company_3', 202005, 202006, 5754.51),
    ('company_3', 202006, 202006, 15944.31),
    ('company_3', 202005, 202007, 6857.47),
    ('company_3', 202006, 202007, 19114.26),
    ('company_3', 202007, 202007, 374.97),
    ('company_3', 202005, 202008, 1052.96),
    ('company_3', 202006, 202008, 28627.23),
    ('company_3', 202007, 202008, 349.5),
    ('company_3', 202008, 202008, 5266.82),
    ('company_3', 202005, 202009, 1638.07),
    ('company_3', 202006, 202009, 4023.55),
    ('company_3', 202007, 202009, 325),
    ('company_3', 202008, 202009, 943.05);
```

My expected output is the following, which I hope can also highlight my explanation.

```
-- Expected Output:
+-----------+------------------+-----------+
|           | reporting_period | gross_sum |
+-----------+------------------+-----------+
| company_1 | 202008           | 14823.74  |
| company_2 | 202008           | 148155.7  |
| company_3 | 202008           | 85839.65  |
| company_1 | 202009           | 17016.11  |
| company_2 | 202009           | 164894.5  |
| company_3 | 202009           | 92769.32  |
+-----------+------------------+-----------+
```

I am hoping to aggregate this by `company` and `reporting_period`. I want to display the `SUM(gross)` for each company in each reporting period by creating a rolling gross sum. Each reporting period should contain the gross sum `BETWEEN 0 AND 5` months of `reporting_period`s. I believe `starting_period`s should be within the same range.

For example, for `reporting_period` 202009 `company_1` should `SUM(gross)` for the records below.

```
+-----------+-----------------+------------------+---------+
| company   | starting_period | reporting_period | gross   |
+-----------+-----------------+------------------+---------+
| company_1 | 202004          | 202004           | 1511.25 |
| company_1 | 202004          | 202005           | 5687    |
| company_1 | 202004          | 202006           | 2359.47 |
| company_1 | 202004          | 202007           | 1725.73 |
| company_1 | 202004          | 202008           | 3540.29 |
| company_1 | 202004          | 202009           | 2192.37 |
+-----------+-----------------+------------------+---------+
-- Total Gross: 17016.11
```

I tried using my prior post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64794361/creating-rolling-periods) but without success. I have also tried a rather messy solution via `SUM(CASE WHEN ... THEN)` but I was also unsuccessful and would prefer to get the expected output. I am missing something but I have not been able to figure out where I am going wrong. Thanks in advance for your help.

**Edit:**

Utilizing this code chunk the gross is far larger than the expected result. The same happens if I remove the `PARTITION BY company`. The data has slightly changed since the prior post example.

I joined the calendar table from my prior post in this set as I was still not obtaining the correct SUM which probably occurred because I made toy data that didn't match my actual data as closely as I thought. I have since added the `company` and  `starting_period` and joined the calendar table to match the example set provided. I also expanded the calendar table as suggested. I thought I'd be able to extrapolate the prior result to my actual data but I haven't had success getting the expected result.

I did some checks on the overall data in excel and can get the expected sum but am having difficulty writing the SQL to produce the desired result.

```
SELECT t.company
       -- ,t.starting_period
       ,t.reporting_period
       ,SUM(SUM(t.gross)) OVER (-- PARTITION BY t.company
                                             ORDER BY t.reporting_period -- , t.starting_period
                                             ROWS BETWEEN 5 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
                                             ) rolling_6_months
FROM #test t
GROUP BY t.company
         -- ,t.starting_period
         ,t.reporting_period
```

```
-- Example Output from the code above for one of the desired reporting periods
+-----------+------------------+------------------+
| company   | reporting_period | rolling_6_months |
+-----------+------------------+------------------+
| company_1 | 202009           | 103655.92        |
+-----------+------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: can you let us know what is wrong with `GMB` solution ?

Comment: @Squirrel thanks for taking a look I have edited my post to include some of the prior code, additional explanation, and an output from one of the reporting periods from the code used